# How to use the HWUT unit test tool with java files

Tags: java, unit-testing, hwut

I've been using the HWUT unit test tool with C and python and now I'm trying it with Java. In python I can tell HWUT to run all .py files with python if I specify a "hwut-info.dat" file as

```
Some title
----------------------
python *.py
```

But for Java I can't do that, because java expects the file names without extension. The java compiler shall consider the '`*.java`' files but it does 
expect the file stem as input, i.e. `java FileStem` in order to treat `FileStem.java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later HWUT versions (> 0.28.0) will provide some sophisticated functionality to
pass information about path names, i.e. in those (at the time of this writing)
'future versions' the usage of an extension-less java file can be specified as

```
  java -cp mypackages:. {{file.java%}}
```

For the time being, you need a script to run your test, such as 'runjava.sh':

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
java -cp ../../package:. $(basename ${1%.*}) ${@:2}
```

It calls the java interpreter, cuts the extension from the filename and passes
all remaining arguments to the file to be executed. In your 'hwut-info.dat'
file you need to specify:

```
My title
--------------------------------------------------------
bash ./runjava.sh *.class
```

This lets HWUT search for *.class files in the current directory. The
'runjava.sh', though, omits the extension and calls 'java' with the file stem.
Inside your Java test application you reflect on the command line like:

```
public class Mine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if( args.length >= 1 && args[0].equals("--hwut-info") ) {
            System.out.println("Title ...");
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```